# IoC registration across multiple projects/solutions - when does it happen?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control

I'm a little confused regarding IoC registration. Assuming I have a Visual Studio project called 'Project 1'. Within this project is a dependent and it's dependency. I register the dependency implementation *within* an installer in Project 1.

Now Project 2 wants to use the dependent described in Project 1. Am I right in saying Project 2 must now do the same registration for the dependency we inject into the dependent? i.e. isn't the registration in Project 1 pointless?

The reason I ask is because I was under the impression the registration was *all* done by the calling code, the 'final consumer' of these implementations. But I've seen installer files within the 'Project 1' equivalent in a solution i'm looking at.

Comment: Usually the dependencies would be registered in the start, but you could delegate that job to the dependants if you like. It's actually quite a nice way to handle it.

Comment: By 'in the start' do you mean within project 1? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yes, the project that starts everything. So for a web site, that would be the web project for example.

Comment: Ah ok, so project 2 in this case then. I've named the projects poorly for the sake of this example I think.

Comment: Yes, that looks right. But as long as the dependencies have been registered with the same container, it should all just plug together.

Comment: Take a look at the concept of the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). Only a Composition Root should register dependencies and only a start-up project should have a Composition Root.